# c# - Access running object reference from another class

Tags: object, reference, mutex

I am new to c#. I have one c# application already running.It is a mutex class which not allows to create multiple instances. so i need get access to some methods inside that class. in order to do that i need to get the running object reference in second class. how can i solve this in c#. plz help me.

Is there any way to retrieve reference objects using ROT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its not that easy to retrieve information from a running application.
I do not know your requirement but if you want to retrieve or store information from application you may use a configuration file which essentially a xml file or you may store required information in some file and then retrieve that in other one.
[This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815786) link can help you in that case.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Ok. I will try it in this way. Thank you very much for you guidance.

Comment: Its my pleasure, if I had been of any help, don't forget to mark it as answer if it helps.